# Filter data in other page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one table which is for contracts , And I have link beside each contract , when I click to the link they transfer to other page which is contract month but i want to display the data only for that contract which I click not all data.

Contact View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

        @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")

            <table class="table table-bordered f" cellspacing="0">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>


                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Num)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Start)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_End)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.typeOfRent.TypeOfRent_Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmountOfRent)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.customers.Customer_Name)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sections.Section_Name)
                            </td>


                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth")
                            </td>


                    </tbody>
                }
            </table>
```

contract month view :

```
   foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.Contract_Num)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Monthe)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.AmountOfRent)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Receipt)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @{
                    var Balance = item.contracts.AmountOfRent - item.Receipt;
                                }

                                @Balance
                            </td>
```

Contract month controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   var ContractMonth =_context.ContractMonth.Include(s => s.contracts).ToList();

      return View(ContractMonth);

    }
```

Comment: Could you please add full `Contact View` ? So I can help you.

Comment: i add now can see the Q now

Comment: But i delete the head of table because the code is long

Comment: And how you display `ContractMonth` in when click after action link? Could you please add this view also?

Comment: Ok i will add ..

Comment: What is the type of your model inside Contract Month View? means its `@model IEnumerable<>` ?

Comment: i was add now  ..

Comment: @model IEnumerable<RES.Models.ContractMonth>
this

Comment: If you want to display only contract data then why you take `@model IEnumerable<RES.Models.ContractMonth>` why not `@model RES.Models.Contracts` ?

Comment: ok i will try , i was add pic , so when i click to the contract month they will transfer to the other page but , the contract number must be filter to the same number it is clearer ?

Comment: By analyzing you pics, the contract month may be one or more for respective contract, right?

Comment: yes ,, so when i click to the contract month all the month will be show but for one contract not all

Comment: yes got it. answer updated try it and let me know :)

Comment: ok thank you i will try now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all change your `Index` action method inside `ContractMonthController` to get specific records with respect to `ContractId`

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var contractMonth = _context.ContractMonth.Where(c => c.ContractsId == id).Include(s => s.contracts).ToList();

    return View(contractMonth);    
}
```

And then change your action to accept `id` as query string parameter,

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth", new { id = item.Contracts_Id }, null)
</td>
```

Comment: please show your `Route.config` in App_start folder

Comment: Ok , i was add pic , so when i click to the contract month they will transfer to the other page but , the contract number must be filter to the same number it is clearer ?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

Comment: now the problem is when i add this     @Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth", new { id = item.Contracts_Id }) it is not open i mean the link

Comment: Make sure no any route present above the `Default` route and check in browser that how link shown in inspect element

Comment: http://localhost:57111/Contracts?Length=13 this what is show in browser when i click, to the link

Comment: No this is wrong it should be look like = > localhost:57111/ContractMonth/Index?id=123

Comment: Yes for that it is not open , but i write the same code , how i can solve this error ?

Comment: Use this => `@Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth", new { id = item.Contracts_Id }, null)`

Comment: Plus one for being sharp-witted.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the primary key (e.g. `Id`) of each `contract` to the `url` of each link as a query string. Then when getting the `contract month` data you can use the `pk` parameter to filter the data, for example (in the `contract month controller`):

```
  public ActionResult Index(int contractId)
  {
      var ContractMonth =_context.ContractMonth.Where(c => c.ContractId == contractId).Include(s => s.contracts).ToList();
      return View(ContractMonth);
    }
```

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper Yes it is.

Comment: i get this error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ContractsId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'RES.Controllers.ContractMonthController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Have you added `contractId` to the link you are clicking on?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth", new { id = item.Contracts_Id })

Comment: you mean like this ? when i do this the link not open

Comment: Since in the example the parameter is named `contractId` therefore it needs to have the same name for the query string: `@Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth", new { contractId = item.Contracts_Id })`

Comment: i was add pic , so when i click to the contract month they will transfer to the other page but , the contract number must be filter to the same number it is clearer ?

Comment: No when i click to the link it is not open when i add new function

Comment: Using the element inspector of the browser, please check what is the html generated for the link that you are defining by razor.

Comment: http://localhost:57111/Contracts?Length=13 this what is show in browser when i click, to the link

Comment: I meant the link for: `@Html.ActionLink("Contract Month", "Index", "ContractMonth", new { contractId = item.Contracts_Id })` It must be: `localhost:57111/ContractMonth/Index?contractId =13`